# Swift: Update CollectionView Cell Image

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Im making a game that has a collectionView character select at the bottom of the GameScene. Many of the characters are locked, so i display a "Locked" image as the collection view cell image. However, when the user unlocks the character and they load the GameScene again(move to gameOver scene, restart the game back to present GameScene), i need to update the collectionView cells images and swap out the "Locked" image with the regular image. Ive tried so many different things but it isn't working. It won't swap out/reload the new images. I know its just something small I'm missing but heres all my code associated with the collection view.

```
class CharactersCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

//MARK : Public API
var characters : NACharacters!{
    didSet{
        updateUI()
    }
}

//MARK : Private
@IBOutlet weak var featuredImageView: UIImageView!


private func updateUI(){
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    self.layer.borderWidth = 2.5
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.layer.cornerRadius  = CGFloat(roundf(Float(self.frame.size.width/2.0)))
    featuredImageView.image = characters.featuredImage
}

}
```

---

```
class NACharacters {

var featuredImage : UIImage!

static var characterLineUp = [NACharacters]()

init(featuredImage: UIImage){

    self.featuredImage = featuredImage
}

static func createCharacters() -> [NACharacters]{

    print("Inside create character")

    characterLineUp.insert(NACharacters(featuredImage: UIImage(named: "DiploSquadCollectionView")!), atIndex: 0)


    characterLineUp.insert(NACharacters(featuredImage: UIImage(named: "LockedNBAPlayersCollectionView")!), atIndex: 1)
    if(NSUserDefaults().unlockNBAPlayers == true){
        characterLineUp[1].featuredImage = UIImage(named: "NBAPlayersCollectionView")!
    }


    characterLineUp.insert(NACharacters(featuredImage: UIImage(named: "LockedLeanSquadCollectionView")!), atIndex: 2)
    if(NSUserDefaults().totalDabs >= 10000){
        print("setting up lean to be unlocked")
        characterLineUp[2].featuredImage = UIImage(named: "LeanSquadCollectionView")!
    }

    return characterLineUp
  }
}
```

---

```
//Inside Game View Controller
@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

//MARK : Data Source
internal var characters = NACharacters.createCharacters()

extension GameViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate{

func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return characters.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(Storyboard.CellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CharactersCollectionViewCell

    cell.characters = self.characters[indexPath.item]

    return cell
}
```

---

```
//Inside Game Scene
    var collectionView: UICollectionView? {
    return self.view?.subviews.filter{ $0 is UICollectionView }.first as? UICollectionView
}

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
//INSIDE HERE I NEED TO UPDATE THE COLLECTION VIEW CELL IMAGES
}
```

I know this looks like a lot of code but most of it is pretty standard. I show you all of this so that we can pin point exactly whats wrong or what needs to be done to get this to work. This is all of my code associated with the collectionView.

Comment: You shouldn't have to filter the subViews of your own subclass controller to find the collectionView. Can you share the hierarchy of the `Inside Game Scene` in relation to the `Inside Game View Controller`?

Comment: @kezi I filter the subViews because when the game would restart it would set the collectionView to nil, this resolved that issue. However, I don't think it is related to the issue I am having now with the CollectionViewCell images.What do you mean by hierarchy of the Inside Game Scene. Sorry I'm a little new to swift haha.

Comment: Yeah I was just saying that you could keep a reference to the collection view so that you don't have to guess with an `?` optional. By hierarchy I meant which view was in which. Was the scene inside of the controller's view? And is the collection view in the same view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you try this in same place ::

```
imageView.image = nil
```

then set the image you want to update as ..

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named : "YourImage")
```

Comment: Yes. I tried doing something similar inside of the didMoveToView function. Didn't work.

Comment: I believe the issue has to do with moving to the GameOverScene and then going back to GameScene. It must not be reloading the cells. You can see in the GameScene I had to declare "collectionView" with a return in order for it to not be nil when I present the GameScene again after a game over.

Comment: 1> try to reload collectionView in viewWillAppear() if It will not work then 2> set logic in itemAtIndexPath() use NSUserDefault() if needed. Understand the problem first. It is 99% reuse cell issue..

Comment: I don't have a viewWillAppear function. Could you edit your answer to have the logic in itemAtIndexPath() using NSUserDefault()? Yes! I do think it is a reuse cell issue as well.

Comment: I added this "if(NSUserDefaults().totalDabs >= 10000){
            print("setting up lean to be unlocked")
           self.characters[2].featuredImage = UIImage(named: "LeanSquadCollectionView")!
        }"  inside of "cellForItemAtIndexPath" function and it worked. However only updated when I moved the collectionView

Answer (score 0):

When you need to 'refresh' a Collection View, tell it to reload its data, then all the images should update as needed.

`collectionView.reloadData()`